# JavaFx on Eclipse View

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, javafx, eclipse-rcp

I am designing an eclipse plugin in eclipse 3.6. I have created a eclipse view by extending the eclipse ViewPart class. Inside the view i am trying to use the JavaFx components like label, text fields etc. In the view i have a label and a text field.

**Problem:** I cannot make the text field editable and the text field does not gain focus on mouse click on the text field.

How can i make the text field to gain focus and make it editable?

Using: Eclipse 3.6 helios and JavaFx 2.2 with Java 7.

```
import java.awt.Frame;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.awt.SWT_AWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart;

public class InputView extends ViewPart {

    Device device = Display.getCurrent();
    Color whiteColor = new Color(device, 255, 255, 255);
    Color redColor = new Color(device, 255, 0, 0);

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(final Composite parent) {
        Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.EMBEDDED
                | SWT.NO_BACKGROUND);
        final Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(composite);

        final JPanel parentPanel = new JPanel();

        final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();

        final TabPane tPane = new TabPane();
        Tab firstTab = new Tab("First Tab");

        GridPane gPane = new GridPane();
        gPane.setHgap(10.0);
        gPane.setVgap(10.0);

        final TextField tField = new TextField();
        tField.setPrefWidth(100.0);
        tField.setEditable(true);
        tField.managedProperty().bind(tField.editableProperty());
        tField.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black; -fx-border-width: 2");

        Label userName = new Label("User Name");

        gPane.add(userName, 0, 0);
        gPane.add(tField, 1, 0);

        firstTab.setContent(gPane);
        tPane.getTabs().add(firstTab);

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Scene scene = new Scene(tPane);
                fxPanel.setScene(scene);

                parentPanel.add(fxPanel);
                frame.add(parentPanel);
                frame.setSize(1300, 600);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setFocus() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: I believe you should use `FXCanvas` rather than `SWT_AWT` (see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swt_interoperability/jfxpub-swt_interoperability.htm))

Comment: Yeah.. Using Fxcanvas resolved my problem.. Thank you.